# Make PHP Storm Aware of Singleton Classes

Tags: php, design-patterns, ide, singleton, phpstorm

I have a piece of code like below and it works perfectly fine but PHP Storm doesn't show code completion and I am unable to CTRL+click to open the method. Is there a way to make PHP storm aware of the method's location for quicker opening?

```
$data= MyCoolBusinessManager::Instance()->GetSomeData();
```

Just an FYI, I am also making use of the spl_autoload_register() function instead of having includes all over the place since my classes follow a standard naming format.

Comment: try Cntrl + Alt + Shift + N and just enter the method name.

Comment: 1) *"Is there a way to make PHP storm aware of the method's location for quicker opening?"* What methods? Examples please, screenshots. 2) *" I am also making use of the spl_autoload_register() function instead"* Makes no difference -- IDE is considering classes across WHOLE project (and other referenced pathas)

Answer (score 7):

You need to put a PHPDoc comment on the Instance() function in your singleton, that says your singleton function return a type of that class:

```
/**
* @return MyCoolBusinessManager
*/
```