# Make PhpStorm Aware of inherited Singleton Classes

Tags: php, singleton, phpstorm

I have following code in the **Parent Class**:

```
class parent {
    /**
     * Memory of the instances of the classes.
     * @since  1.0.0
     * @access protected
     * @static
     * @var array
     */
    protected static $instances = [];

    /**
     * Singleton
     * Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45500679/8148987
     * @since  1.0.0
     * @access public
     * @static
     * @return object
     */
    public static function instance() {

        if ( empty( self::$instances[static::class] ) ) {
            $instance                       = new static();
            self::$instances[static::class] = $instance;
        } else {
            $instance = self::$instances[static::class];
        }

        return $instance;
    }
}
```

The **Child Class**:

```
class child extends parent {

    public function test() {

    }

}
```

I can do following with this code:

```
$class_child = child::instance();
```

But PhpStorm is not aware of the `test()` method.

If I write `$class_child->` no proposals are listed. What can I do?

The solution mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32014968/8148987 will not work in my case.

Comment: `@return static` should do the job instead of generic `@return object`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@return static` instead of `@return object` in PHPDoc for `instance()` method.

Right now PHPDoc tells that this method returns some object (can be any object).

With `@return static` it will return instance of a class where that `instance()` method was used. So for `ChildClass` it will be interpreted as  `@return ChildClass`, for `GrandChildClass` it will be `@return GrandChildClass`.